# copy values to another mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that displays fields sent from a form. There are buttons that can edit or delete selected row by selecting id. I want to add a button that would insert selected row to another table. I cannot get it to work.

Here's the code for the table:

```
    <?php
/* 
  VIEW.PHP
  Displays all data from 'players' table
*/

  // connect to the database
  include('config2.php');

  // get results from database
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

  // display data in table
  echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
  echo "<tr> <th>Author</th> <th>Email</th> <th>Title</th> <th>Poem</th> <th>id</th>";

  // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['Name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['content'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="publish.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Publish</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
  } 

  // close table>
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here's the code for delete function:

```
 // connect to the database
 include('config2.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // delete the entry
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM stories WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: secret.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: secret.php");
 }
```

And here's how I think the function to insert the row to other table should look like but its not working

```
// connect to the database
 include('config2.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id values
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 $email = $_GET['email']; 
 $title = $_GET['title'];
 $content = $_GET['content'];


 //upload
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT into publish (name, email, title, content)
  VALUES WHERE name=$name, email=$email, title=$title, content=$content")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: secret.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: secret.php");
 }
```

I'm new at this so not sure what the correct syntax would look like in this case

Comment: This code seems a bit all over the place. 1) the publish link is not a form, nor does it have the data you are requesting (e.g. `$_GET['name']`) 2) Your INSERT SQL query looks wrong. Not sure why you have a WHERE in there. 3) You're open to SQL injection as you're putting user data directly into your query, or at least you would be if you weren't 4) trying to add random literal strings the query without quotes.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say it "isn't working." What is or is not happening? If you're getting an error, please detail it. If something is not happening, please clarify which thing isn't happening, and what action should cause it.

Comment: I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE name=, email=, title=, content=' at line 2"

Answer (score 0):

```
    Using select query  

            $id = $_GET['id'];
   $result = mysql_query("select *stories WHERE id=$id")
             or die(mysql_error()); 
            $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$query= mysql_query("INSERT INTO publish (name, email, title, content)
                     VALUES ('$row['Name']','$row['Email']',$row['title'],$row['content'])");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about any `PHP` related stiff but have you looked at your `INSERT` statement. It's completely wrong. You can't use a `WHERE` condition in `INSERT` statement as shown below

```
INSERT into publish (name, email, title, content)
  VALUES WHERE name=$name, ....
          ^------ Here
```

Did you rather meant to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
INSERT into publish (name, email, title, content)
  SELECT name, email, title, content
FROM Article
WHERE name=$name, email=$email, title=$title, content=$content"
```

(OR) just an `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT into publish (name, email, title, content)
  VALUES($name, $email, $title, $content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sub select if u want but i dont know about performance in large table

```
Insert into tablea (name,xx,xxx) value ('select name  from table b where id=x' ,'select xx  from table b where id=x ', 'select xxx  from table b where id=x') not tested but it shoild work
```